# Why does oxidized copper become green?

Tags: elements, oxidation-state, color

Why does oxidized copper turn green? I am sorry if this question is too basic, but am really stumped here. It would be helpful if one could provide a research paper or website with your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copper *oxide* is not green, but green [*verdigris*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verdigris), basic copper carbonate (or acetate) forms on copper exposed to air and moisture.

Heating copper in air [*can* form a near-transparent film of copper oxide, which can exhibit all the colors of the spectrum](http://jguz.blogspot.com/2005/12/so-this-thanksgiving-was-speant-with.html) due to interference of light. The same effect cause a "rainbow" in oil slicks on water.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, just says how not why. I am imagining some kind of answer with d-orbitals.

Comment: The question is a misstatement. Read it

Comment: Huh, I still don't see it, it sounds like someone's asking for an explanation for the color change of copper when it's oxidized. Oxidized does not mean "gains oxygen".   I think Aaron is trying to understand why copper carbonate and/or copper acetate are green.

Answer (score 1):

Copper when is exposed to air, it gets oxidized and a tarnish of green color is formed on it.As Cu is a transition metal, it possesses color according to the "crystal field theory". 
So, Cu reflects green color when it comes in contact with oxygen.